# Beginner web scraper for Nagios

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am attempting to learn Python. It was suggested to me to try a web scraper, so I thought to get myself to look at multiple Nagios instances. I have not programmed in Python before, but learned from other code reviews to adapt my standards to PEP8. The online checker says the code passes.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import urllib.request
import time

allNagiosInfo = [
    ('http://example.com/nagios', 'user', 'password', 'Basic'),
    ('https://network2.example.com/nagios', 'user', 'password', 'Digest'),
    ('https://anothernetwork.example.com/nagios', 'user', 'password', 'Basic')]

for nagiosEntry in allNagiosInfo:
    nagiosBaseURL = nagiosEntry[0]
    nagiosUsername = nagiosEntry[1]
    nagiosPassword = nagiosEntry[2]
    nagiosAuthType = nagiosEntry[3]
    # print("Current values: {}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(
    #      nagiosBaseURL, nagiosUsername, nagiosPassword, nagiosAuthType))

    if nagiosAuthType == "Basic":
        response = requests.get(nagiosBaseURL + "/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all",
                                auth=HTTPBasicAuth(nagiosUsername,
                                                   nagiosPassword))
    if nagiosAuthType == "Digest":
        response = requests.get(nagiosBaseURL + "/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all",
                                auth=HTTPDigestAuth(nagiosUsername,
                                                    nagiosPassword))

    html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    for i, items in enumerate(html.select('td')):
        if i == 3:
            hostsAll = items.text.split('\n')
            hostsUp = hostsAll[12]
            hostsDown = hostsAll[13]
            hostsUnreachable = hostsAll[14]
            hostsPending = hostsAll[15]
            hostsProblems = hostsAll[24]
            hostsTypes = hostsAll[25]
        if i == 12:
            serviceAll = items.text.split('\n')
            serviceOK = serviceAll[13]
            serviceWarning = serviceAll[14]
            serviceUnknown = serviceAll[15]
            serviceCritical = serviceAll[16]
            serviceProblems = serviceAll[26]
            serviceTypes = serviceAll[27]
        # print(i, items.text) ## To get the index and text
    print("Nagios Server at {}@{}:".format(nagiosUsername, nagiosBaseURL))
    print("    Hosts")
    print("\tUp          - {}".format(hostsUp))
    print("\tDown        - {}".format(hostsDown))
    print("\tUnreachable - {}".format(hostsUnreachable))
    print("\tPending     - {}".format(hostsPending))
    print("\tProblems    - {}".format(hostsProblems))
    print("\tTypes       - {}".format(hostsTypes))

    print("    Services")
    print("\tOK          - {}".format(serviceOK))
    print("\tWarning     - {}".format(serviceWarning))
    print("\tUnknown     - {}".format(serviceUnknown))
    print("\tCritical    - {}".format(serviceCritical))
    print("\tProblems    - {}".format(serviceProblems))
    print("\tTypes       - {}".format(serviceTypes))
    # print("Request returned:\n\n{}".format(html.text))
    # To get the full request
```

Currently, it outputs my three instances properly:

```
Nagios Server at user@http://example.com/nagios:
    Hosts
        Up          - 24
        Down        - 0
        Unreachable - 0
        Pending     - 0
        Problems    - 0
        Types       - 24
    Services
        OK          - 142
        Warning     - 0
        Unknown     - 0
        Critical    - 0
        Problems    - 0
        Types       - 142
Nagios Server at user@https://network2.example.com/nagios:
    Hosts
        Up          - 3
        Down        - 0
        Unreachable - 0
        Pending     - 0
        Problems    - 0
        Types       - 3
    Services
        OK          - 28
        Warning     - 0
        Unknown     - 0
        Critical    - 0
        Problems    - 0
        Types       - 28
Nagios Server at user@https://anothernetwork.example.com/nagios:
    Hosts
        Up          - 56
        Down        - 0
        Unreachable - 0
        Pending     - 0
        Problems    - 0
        Types       - 56
    Services
        OK          - 130
        Warning     - 0
        Unknown     - 0
        Critical    - 0
        Problems    - 0
        Types       - 130
```

I understand I do not have error checking (i.e. is the username/password correct? Auth Type correct? Server URL right?), so that will be my next thing to learn. I also understand I should not have variables (especially with passwords) hard-coded into the code, but I do not know what is the "proper" way of dealing with secure variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) I'd recommend you follow the best practices.

### Naming conventions

- `allNagiosInfo` -> this is most likely a constant, so: `ALL_NAGIOS_INFO`
- `nagiosEntry`, `nagiosBaseURL`, `nagiosUsername`, `nagiosPassword`, `nagiosAuthType` -> `nagios_entry`, `nagios_base_url`, `nagios_username`, `nagios_password`, `nagios_auth_type`.

And so on with the naming, you got the idea.

**Summary:**

> Variable names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.

### Imports

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> - Standard library imports.
> - Related third party imports.
> - Local application/library specific imports.
> - You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

Also, don't import modules that you're not using (e.g: `time`, `urllib`).
So, that means you could rewrite your imports as follows:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth, HTTPDigestAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

---

This:

```py
nagios_base_url = nagios_entry[0]
nagios_username = nagios_entry[1]
nagios_password = nagios_entry[2]
nagios_auth_type = nagios_entry[3]
```

Can be rewritten as:

`nagios_base_url, nagios_username, nagios_password, nagios_auth_type = nagios_entry`

Since all the requests that you're doing are suffixed with the same url, I'd just define that before the `if`s:

```py
# ...
for nagios_entry in ALL_NAGIOS_INFO:
    nagios_base_url, nagios_username, nagios_password, nagios_auth_type = nagios_entry
    full_url = "{}/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all".format(nagios_base_url)

    if nagios_auth_type == "Basic":
        response = requests.get(full_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(nagios_username, nagios_password))

    if nagios_auth_type == "Digest":
        response = requests.get(full_url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(nagios_username, nagios_password))
```

You have way too many prints which can be rewritten as a single print:

```py
print("""Nagios Server at {}@{}: 

Hosts:

    Up          - {}
    Down        - {}
    Unreachable - {}
    Pending     - {}
    Problems    - {}
    Types       - {}

Services:

    OK          - {}
    Warning     - {}
    Unknown     - {}
    Critical    - {}
    Problems    - {}
    Types       - {}
""".format(
        nagios_username, nagios_base_url, hosts_up, hosts_down, hosts_unreachable, hosts_pending,
        hosts_problems, hosts_types, service_ok, service_warning, service_unknown, service_critical,
        service_problems, service_types
    )
)
```

You can also look at [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) if you want to play around with the `\t`s.

---

### Security

As you said, it's not recommended to keep your passwords in the code. There's no perfect solution for this, but we can enumerate some of the most used ones:

- config files which have to be added to `.gitignore` so they get excluded from the repo
- environment variables (mostly used on Unix based distros)
- some powerful hashing technique to generate a master password (master password -> secure key-> encrypt data by the key)

---

### Scraping

When scraping things, you can usualy go a specific element by using an `xpath` or a `selector`. I usually use the `lxml` module when I have to quickly put together something because it allows me to use xpaths (though bs might as well offer that - didn't actually play with that for a while now)

**Example for lxml usage**

```py
from lxml import html
import requests

res = requests.get(some_url)
tree = html.fromstring(res.content)
tds = tree.xpath('//table//td[@class="plaintext"]/text()[normalize-space()]')
```

---

Now, your code is not very portable and if you plan on adding more servers, you'll find yourself having a hard time integrating those as well. The first thing that I'd do is to find the proper data structure for my data. In your scenario, a dictionary looks like the best choice out there:

```py
NAGIOS_DATA = {
    'http://example.com/nagios/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all': {
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'password',
        'auth_type': 'Basic'
    },
    'https://network2.example.com/nagios/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all': {
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'password',
        'auth_type': 'Digest'
    },
    'https://anothernetwork.example.com/nagios/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all': {
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'password',
        'auth_type': 'Basic'
    },
}
```

*INFO: don't forget that the `password` can be defined in a config file and imported here*

Now, that's debatable if it's the best structure that you can use because I don't know the entire logic of your app, but it'll do for now.

Using the above, we can now do:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth, HTTPDigestAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


NAGIOS_DATA = {
    'http://example.com/nagios/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all': {
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'password',
        'auth_type': 'Basic'
    },
    'https://network2.example.com/nagios/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all': {
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'password',
        'auth_type': 'Digest'
    },
    'https://anothernetwork.example.com/nagios/cgi-bin/status.cgi?host=all': {
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'password',
        'auth_type': 'Basic'
    },
}


def get_url_response(url, user, password, auth_type):
    """Get the response from a URL.

    Args:
        url (str): Nagios url
        user (str): Nagios username
        password (str): Nagios password
        auth_type (str): Nagios auth_type

    Returns: Response object
    """

    if auth_type == "Basic":
        return requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)) 
    return requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(user, password))


def main():
    """
    Main entry to the program.
    """

    for url, auth_data in NAGIOS_DATA.items():
        user, password, auth_type = auth_data["user"], auth_data["password"], auth_data["auth_type"]
        response = get_url_response(url, user, password, auth_type)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
            # ... and so on


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I haven't finished the whole review because I want you to go ahead and do the rest. Some things that I've added to the program:

- functions: writing functions will let you reuse the functionality they contain at a later point + it's easier to test the code inside them. *Homework: could you think of a way of splitting them even further?*
- [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/): having docstrings within a function will tell others (and most important, the future-you) what that function does.

Comment: Note, many put spaces between the different import groups, due to `isort` - the industry standard import hinter. Also the big print would be nicer as an f-string or with explicit format names.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed review! I have it working with a couple new functions now, naming convention used, and the dictionary for variables. One question though, if I find out how to import settings from a config file, would the `NAGIOS_DATA` still be a constant?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Yep.

Comment: Awesome, got a config file going now! Thanks! Should I post a new question for further review?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Yep

Comment: New question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/236127/37991)